# Custom UITable in FBFriendPickerViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

I would like to know if there is any way to completely replace FBFriendPickerViewController's UITableView or modify the current one.
I need to reverse colors on the table ( white labels, black background) and I wasn't able to do that. So far, I was able to replace table's background but nothing else worked.

I tried something like:

```
self.myFriendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
self.myFriendPicker.delegate = self;
[self.myFriendPicker loadData];
[self.myFriendPicker clearSelection];
self.myFriendPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
self.myFriendPicker.view.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 250, 340);
```

And then I tried to create a new UITableView with red background to try it out and see if it works.

```
 UITableView *tbView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tbView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.myFriendPicker.tableView = tbView;
```

It didn't work and I would appreciate some suggestions.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own fabecookfriendpicker as a subview of uitableview.Displayinging the list of your friends is not a big issue but even though It is not a straightforward task since you need to lazy load the images and so on.

You have more opportunities to custumize the view with approach.But you can also try subclassing the FBFriendPickerViewController itself

Comment: I ended up using standard facebook iOS friend picker. Thanks for your time.